# How to get Extended advertising data using android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I am working on Nordic nrf52840 which is broadcasting extended advertising, thanks to the people on stackoverflow I can finally find my device, now the only function left is to dump extended advertising data to log, I found out that ScanResult contain may have contain the adv data I need but when I tried to dump it to log it show only {} why and how can I read adv data.

```
package com.example.tryble_scanner;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult;
import android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter  = null;
private BluetoothLeScanner mBluetoothLeScanner = null;
public static final int REQUEST_BT_PERMISSIONS = 0;
public static final int REQUEST_BT_ENABLE = 1;
private boolean mScanning = false;
private Handler mHandler = null;

private ScanCallback mLeScanCallBack1 = new ScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
                //super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                 String data=ConverttoString(result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData());
                BluetoothDevice btdevice = result.getDevice();
                Log.d("BLE", btdevice.getAddress());
                Log.d("BLE",data);
            }
            @Override
            public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
                Log.d("BLE", "error");
            }
};

private  ScanCallback mLeScanCallBack2=new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
        Log.d("BLE","scan stop");
    }
    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        Log.d("BLE","stop scan failed");
    }
};

   private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallBack3=new 
 BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
   @Override
   public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice, int i, byte[] bytes) {

   }
   };
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnScan);
    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
    mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    this.mHandler = new Handler();
}

public void stop_scan(View view) {
    Log.d("Ble","scan stop pressed");
//        mBluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(mLeScanCallback2);
    mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().stopScan(mLeScanCallBack2);
}

public void onBtnScan(View view) {
    Log.i("Btn","get click");
    checkBTPermission();
    String[] names=new String[]{"Auden test"};
    List<ScanFilter> filters=null;
    if(names != null){
        filters=new ArrayList<>();
        for(String name:names){
            ScanFilter filter=new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName(name).build();
            filters.add(filter);
        }
    }
    ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
            //.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            //.setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
            //.setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE)
            //.setNumOfMatches(ScanSettings.MATCH_NUM_ONE_ADVERTISEMENT)
            //.setReportDelay(0L)
              .setLegacy(false)
              .build();
    if(mBluetoothLeScanner==null){
        Log.i("BLE","could not get scanner");
    }else{
        mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters,scanSettings,mLeScanCallBack1);  //filters,scanSettings,mLeScanCallback
    }
}

private void checkBTPermission(){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        int pc=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        pc+=this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        if(pc!=0){
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1001);
        }else {
            Log.d("BLE","checkBT permission");
        }
    }
}
 public static String ConverttoString (SparseArray<byte[]> array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return "null";
    }
    if (array.size() == 0) {
        return "{}";
    }
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append('{');
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i) {
        buffer.append(array.keyAt(i)).append("=").append(Arrays.toString(array.valueAt(i)));
    }
    buffer.append('}');
    Log.d("convert",buffer.toString());
    return buffer.toString();
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that your mobile support the necessary feature? See [Bluetooth Low Energy Advertising](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising)

Comment: @Risto I my phone bluetooth version is 5.0